# Export data from Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way to export TFS/VS Online?

We need to import the data to our onpremise environment.

We are running Windows Server 2012 R2 with TFS

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no free tool that can help you with migration from VSO (Visual Studio Online) to TFS (Team Foundation Server)

OpsHub has a paid product that should allow you to do this though.
http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/oim

They have a free version of their tool to migrate from TFS on prem into VSO. Which seems to have been sponsored by Microsoft. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/14/migrating-on-premises-tfs-to-vs-online.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft enabled this for a short while, but it is no longer available.  There is a chance they will enable this again in the future.  See this blog by Brian Harry for more details on the Export feature (about halfway down the post): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/02/21/vs-online-early-adopter-program-extended-to-may-7-2014.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TFS Integration Tools to move your data from VSO to TFS. I have only done this once but it is possible. The TFS Integration Tools are however not hugely friendly and I would recommend contacting an expert

http://nakedalm.com/migration-from-tf-service-to-tf-server-with-the-tfs-integration-platform/